# Should I use a database, json or csv?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, server

I'm currently working on a project called 'pwManager', it is basically meant to store passwords, but since all the information is stored upon my 1tb hard drive, and it is just a *project*, I think that a database may be to heavy of a program on my laptop. In this scenario I was recommended to use a .csv file to store the information, but I was thinking about appending information to a .json file using AJAX. So what should I do?

I don't think that an image is necessary for this question.

Comment: Your question title appears unrelated to the rest of your question.

Comment: The rest of the question is rather an opinionated topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to read it with javascript, using a json file would be easier although a csv file doesn't add that much complexity.